# Choosing correct Projection name for ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, python-2.7, error-999999

I am trying to plug in a projection name to my code, but I think the syntax/name is incorrect.

```
 arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference("US Albers Equal Area Conic")
```

When I run the above it throws:

> RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. the input is not
>   a geographic or projected coordinate system.

I cannot seem to find documentation on how the projection/coordinate system names should be given when using as parameters for `arcpy`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the easiest it to use an existing fc or by providing the epsg code `arcpy.SpatialReference(8075)`, dont know if it is the correct one. If you want to use name you can check it with: `arcpy.SpatialReference(8075).name`

Comment: When you run this code snippet what error does it give?

Comment: When I ran that it threw: `RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
the input is not a geographic or projected coordinate system`.

Comment: It appears that is not a viable `EPSG factoryCode`. 102008 is the correct one. So, `arcpy.SpatialReference(102008).name` returns 'North_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic'. But I am still not sure if I need to use that or "North America Albers Equal Area Conic".

Comment: There are an infinite number of potential Albers Equal Area projections. If you want a specific one, you need to specify it, via file name, integer code, or  well known string. Even "USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic" isn't unique at 10.4.1, because there's also "USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version".  Using integer codes is a whole lot more straight forward (102003 or 102039).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302509/choosing-correct-projection-name-for-arcpy/302534?noredirect=1#comment487400_302509):

> There are an infinite number of potential Albers Equal Area
>   projections. If you want a specific one, you need to specify it, via
>   file name, integer code, or  well known string. Even
>   "USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic" isn't unique at 10.4.1,
>   because there's also
>   "USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version".  Using integer
>   codes is a whole lot more straight forward (102003 or 102039).

so, based on your comment that:

> 102008 is the correct one

I think you should use:

```
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(102008)
```